# How to strip whitespace off a function parameter list preserving the function parameters?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to compress code and would like to know how to modify my regular expression to strip whitespace within a comma separated function arguments list preserving the commas and the arguments. I am slowly narrowing down to match the args and the whitespace but can't figure out how to write the regex to use the cleaned string for further processing.

Source string:

```
function (arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Regular expression:

```
function\((\w+(\s*,\s*))+
```

The resulting string shall look like

```
function(arg1,arg2,arg3)
```

Can you tell me, how, please?

Comment: why not just use str_replace e.g. $no_space =  str_replace(" ", "", $string);

Comment: @user1014412 the above comment would solve this problem If you have any complex case then post it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the tokenizer?